# Format percentage with or without decimal

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a very simple issue in MS-Access and somehow the solution eludes me. I want to display a field that holds a percentage with or without decimals. So I want to display the decimal separator only when there is actually a decimal in the field. This illustrates the problem:

debug.? format(0.21, "0.#%"), format(0.215, "0.#%")
21,%          21,5%

How to get rid of the nasty comma in 21,%. I tired al sorts of format options. I either always get a decimal or I get the value rounded, which I do not want.
How can I display 0.21 as 21% and 0,215 as 21,5% ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **IIf**:

```
PercentValue = Format(Value, "0" & IIf(Value * 100 = Fix(Value * 100), "", ".##") & "%")

Value = 0.21  -> 21%
Value = 0.215 -> 21.5%
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot use an IIF function, because the formatting is passed onto the iGrid active-X control that utilizes the default formatting options from MS-Access to format columns in the grid. I guess I just have to live with the extra 0 if the value is a unbroken number. I hoped it could be done with the default formatting options...